# Deformation of Flux or Circulation Integrals.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

I have recently learnt about Green's Stokes' and the Divergence Theorems. I read here: http://www.supermath.info/CalculusIIIvectorcalculus2011.pdf.
On page 31, it describes a deformation you can make to show that one line integral is equal to another. I also saw a video describing the same idea for the divergence theorem. Here's how it works: 
Suppose there is a field $\vec{F}$ defined on $R^2$ so that $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$, If you have an annulus bounded by C, then:
$$ \oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_R \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)  dA = 0
$$
But:
$$ \oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \oint_{C_1} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} - \oint_{C_2} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = 0 
$$
Thus:
$$\oint_{C_1} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}  = \oint_{C_2} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} 
$$

The same idea applies to the surface boundary of a sphere like region with a hollowed hole in the middle: The flux of the 2 boundaries should be equal when the divergence is $0$ by the Divergence Theorem. The same goes for an annulus surface living in 3D because of Stokes' Theorem when the curl is $0$, since curl$\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} = 0$.

Since I first read about it, I was always confused by this/these idea/s, I mean if the respected operation is $0$, then shouldn't all the boundary integrals also be $0$. For example, referring to the section above; shouldn't we be able to argue:

$$ \oint_{C_1} \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} = \iint_{R_1} \left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)  dA = 0
$$

($R_1$ is the region bounded by $C_1$) I apologize if this should be obvious, but I don't get why these theorems should at all be useful if all the terms are just $0$. Surely I am making a mistake somehow. Thank you for reading thus far, all answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're overlooking in the usefulness of these theorems is the domain of definition of the vector field $F$. Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ be an open subset, and say $F=(P,Q):U\to\Bbb{R}^2$ is a $C^1$ vector field defined on $U$. If $C$ is a closed curve and $R$ is the region bounded by the curve, **AND** $R\subset U$ is completely contained in the domain of the given vector field $F$, then we have Stokes theorem:
\begin{align}
\int_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}&=\int_R\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,dA
\end{align}
If the curl of the vector field vanishes (i.e $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0$ at every point of $U$), then sure, the RHS and hence the LHS are zero. To emphasize the importance of the domain $U$, and the significance of the theorem about deforming the contour/surface, let us consider two examples:

---

**Example 1. Vector field Defined Everywhere**

Consider the smooth vector field $F:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as $F(x,y)=(e^xy, e^x)$. This clearly has vanishing curl. So, for any closed curve $C$ which bounds a region $R$, we have by Stokes theorem that
\begin{align}
\int_C\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}&=\int_R\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,dA = 0
\end{align}
Actually, this is still an interesting result, because $F$ is a vector field with such a special property that its integral over every closed curve which bounds a region vanishes.

Here, I gave a rather simple vector field $F$. I'm sure one can come up with **VERY VERY VERY** complicated vector fields, for which directly calculating the line integral by parametrizing the curve etc is completely unfeasible. However, if you know that the curl is $0$, then one can directly deduce that the integral over closed curves is $0$. You write

> but I don't get why these theorems should at all be useful if all the terms are just 0

but what you're not realizing is that sometimes, showing a certain quantity equals zero is a very powerful statement. i.e knowing it is zero is valuable information in some contexts.

---

**Example 2. Vector field not defined everywhere.**

Here, consider the domain $U=\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, i.e the plane minus the origin. Consider the vector field $G:U\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as
\begin{align}
G(x,y)&=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)
\end{align}
Note that we have to exclude the origin from the domain of definition because otherwise we'd be dividing by $0$, which is of course completely forbidden. You can once again verify directly that at every point of $U$, we have $\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}=0$. Now, suppose for example that $C$ and $R$ are given as in the figure below:[image: region]

If in this case you claim "by Stokes theorem"
\begin{align}
\int_C\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}&=\int_R\left(\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}\right)\,dA = 0
\end{align}

then you'd be completely wrong. This is wrong because one very important hypothesis has not been verified. In this case the bounded region $R$ contains the origin, however, the domain of $G$ is $U=\Bbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, so Stokes theorem is just not applicable to this pair of $C$ and $R$. It is in this case that one uses Stokes theorem to "deform the contour". As I have drawn it, $C$ is rather complicated, so evaluating the line integral is next to impossible. What we can do is consider the following figure
[image]

Here the curve $C$ we consider has two pieces, $C_1$ which is the black curve the same as in the above picture, and $C_2$ which is the new red circle. The region bounded is $R$. Note that in this case, we have specifically ensured that $R$ does not contain the origin, i.e $R\subset U$. So, in this case, Stokes theorem is completely applicable:
\begin{align}
\int_C\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}&=\int_R\left(\frac{\partial G_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial G_1}{\partial y}\right)\,dA = 0
\end{align}
The LHS is $\int_{C_1}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}-\int_{C_2}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}$. Therefore, we get the conclusion
\begin{align}
\int_{C_1}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}&= \int_{C_2}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}
\end{align}
In other words, we have reduced the calculation of the complicated, horrendous, disgusting line integral $\int_{C_1}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}$ over the complicated curve $C_1$ to the line integral over the simple circle $C_2$. In this case, by directly applying the definition of line integrals (i.e parametrizing the circle $C_2$ counterclockwise) one can show that
\begin{align}
\int_{C_1}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r}&= \int_{C_2}\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{r} = 2\pi.
\end{align}

---

Therefore, using Stokes theorem to deform the contour often times simplifies computations. This is just one illustration of the utility of the Stokes theorem.