# Divergence theorem when $\nabla \cdot \vec{F} = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, divergence-theorem

Calculate the flow of the vector field $$\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = \frac{1}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} (x, y, z)$$ out of a sphere with radius $10$ and center at the origin.

This what I did:

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac32} - 3x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3}} = \frac{1-3\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)}{r^3}$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac32} - 3y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3}} = \frac{1-3\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\phi)}{r^3}$$

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = \frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac32} - 3z^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3}} = \frac{1-3\cos^2(\phi)}{r^3}$$

$$ \nabla \cdot \vec{F} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z} = 0 $$

$$\iiint_{V} 0 dV = 0$$
But the correct answer is $4\pi$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $F$ has singularity at $0$, you can't use divergence theorem.

Comment: ^ because of this, you’re better off directly calculating the flux; the answer will be $4\pi$. What the divergence theorem does tell you though, is that the flux across the sphere of radius $10$ (or across the boundary of any smooth willy-wonka 3D-region which contains the origin (e.g an off-centered ellipsoid)) is equal to the flux across the unit sphere. So, even if I asked you for the flux across some weird squidward-shaped volume which contains the origin, the answer is still $4\pi$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Gauss Divergence theorem applicable when the Divergence of a vector field is a dirac delta function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4680350/is-the-gauss-divergence-theorem-applicable-when-the-divergence-of-a-vector-field)

Comment: @peek-a-boo So  I have to do a double surface integral (for vector) for a random surface that contains the singularity. It doesn't matter what the surface looks like. But if I am correct this far, does the surface need to a closed surface?

Answer (score 3):

More generally we can evaluate the flux of $\mathbf{F}$ through any closed surface $S$ oriented outwards which does not pass through the origin:
$$\iint_S \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $(0,0,0)$ is outside $S$,}\\
4\pi & \text{if $(0,0,0)$ is inside $S$,}
\end{cases}$$
see also peek-a-boo's comment above.

In the first case since $\text{div}(\mathbf{F})=0$ (your computations are correct), we may apply the divergence theorem and we find $0$.

In the second case, we can't apply divergence theorem directly to $S$ because we have the singularity $(0,0,0)$ inside $S$, but we may apply the theorem to a domain whose boundary is $S\cup S_r$ where $S_r$ is a sphere with radius $r$ sufficiently small (inward oriented). Since the domain between $S$ and $S_r$ does not contain $(0,0,0)$, we may use the divergence theorem and again we find
$$\iint_{S\cup S_r} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=0$$
which implies
$$\iint_{S} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=-\iint_{S_r} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}=-\iint_{S_r} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\iint_{S_r}\frac{dS}{r^2}=\frac{|S_r|}{r^2}=4\pi.$$
Notice that along $S_r$, with the given inward orientation,
$$\mathbf{F}(x, y, z) = \frac{(x, y, z)}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} =-\frac{r\mathbf{n}}{r^{3/2}}-\frac{\mathbf{n}}{r^2}$$

Comment: not really a dupe, since it uses differential forms terminology, but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4261078/568204) is a very similar question. The sublink [Deformation of Flux or Circulation Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252590/568204) has a picture explaining the idea, in 2D, of deforming the contour of integration, so hopefully OP finds that helpful.

Comment: @RobertZ I don't understand this part "we may apply the theorem to a domain whose boundary is $S∪S_r$"?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp The domain is the interior of $S$ minus a small ball $B_r$ centered at the origin. By removing that ball the resulting domain does not contain the singularity. The boundary of such domain is $S\cup S_r$.

Comment: @RobertZ Is $S_{r}$ and $B_{r}$ the same thing?

Comment: No, $B_r=\{x: \|x\|\leq r\}$, $S_r=\{x: \|x\|=r\}$.

Comment: @RobertZ Okay so $B_{r}$ is the the small sphere that contains the singularity, but didn't you say earlier that $S_{r}$ is a sphere with radius r sufficiently small (inward oriented)? I'm so confused rn.

Comment: Yes, if you remove a solid ball $B_r$ form the interior of $S$, you have a solid with a cavity. The **boundary** of such "solid with a cavity" is $S \cup S_r$.

Comment: So what I understand from every answer is that I have to do a double integral for a random surface that contains the singularity. It doesn't matter what the surface looks like. But if I am correct it doesn't need to a closed surface right?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Here we need closed surface. If a surface is not closed how can you tell that the origin is **inside** or **outside**?

Comment: @RobertZ Good question. I was thinking of this situation more like  a tennis inside a open bucket? And I know it is a horrible analogy but it is the only one I got.